# Classic asp -- better to do lots of response.write or use <%

Tags: asp-classic, context-switch

I'm editing some legacy code in classic ASP that uses a lot of code like the following:

```
pf "<div class=""span-6 last"" style=""margin-top:4px;"">"
pf "<div class=""clean-lightblue-left"" style=""margin-top:4px;"">"
pf "<span style=""float: left; margin-right: 0.3em;"" class=""ui-icon ui-icon-print""></span><a href=""#report"" name=""report"" id=""topic_report_download"">Topic Progress : <b>Download Report</b></a>"
pf "</div></div>"
```

In this example, pf is a utility function that is essentially the same as `response.write` with a line return.

I would rather do something like this:

```
...asp code
%> 
Regular HTML code here
<%
asp code...
```

I'm new to asp, but I've heard of context-switching, and that it can be costly.  Which of these two options is more costly?

Comment: I don't have any references but from my personal experience, I've noticed your first example would perform better than switching back and forth from ASP script blocks and HTML code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me bottom line your specific example.  A series of `Response.Write` calls just carrying plain string literals is going to be slower than including the complete HTML as content outside of the script code.

This idea of "context switching" is a bit of a fallacy as a result of some unfortunate wording in some documentation (or perhaps history).  We tend to think of an ASP file as being HTML with some script interspresed in it using `<% script here %>`.  In fact ASP file is a **script** file with some HTML in it.  Its easier to reason on what its going if you think of it as having html content separated using `%> content here <%` (with an implied `>%` and `<%` at the start and end of the file).

When the file is parsed to p-code a file entirely processable by the script engine is created (there is no "context switching").  In effect `%> .... <%` becomes a special form of Response.Write that sends the content between the `%><%` to the buffer.  The difference is that the bytes come verbatim as they appear in the original ASP file whereas the standard `Response.Write` accepts a Unicode string from VBScript and then has to encode to the `Response.CodePage` a set of bytes to put in the buffer.

Hence the "context switching" is really just the number of times the script has to write to the buffer.  Having many `<% = someExpression %>` in your HTML creates a large number of buffer writes.

These days unless you are generating an insanely large amount HTML (the article Doozer mentions is 10 years old) you would have buffering turned on.  The cost of many writes is quite low.  Reducing them can help but one has to remember that the way VBScript handles string contactenation is not without its problems too.

Comment: I had wondered if it was just essentially a big response.write.  That would make sense, since it just a large block of literals.  Thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 1):

I think plane HTML is good because when you render HTML via response.write it execute two statement like one perform response.write and then render HTML. but when we write HTML code it directly render in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You should read these [ASP Tips to Improve Performance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972335.aspx), but specifically look at [#16](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972335.aspx#asptips_topic16)

> Also, interspersing small amounts of script and HTML causes switching between the script engine and HTML, reducing performance

At the least. Ensure Response.Buffer is set to true. The performance difference between the above may be minimal but, I think the way you want to change it would be better, if I understand how you want to change it. However, it's ultimately your decision to make if you want to change it. I would look to how readable and maintainable the code is for yourself on whether your should change it.